# Как превратить EditText в поток данных для RxJava2?

Tags: android, rxjava, listener, rxandroid, rxjava2

Начал постепенно переходить на реактивное программирование с замечательным фреймворком `RxJava 2` и заинтересовал простейший пример создания потока в динамическом стиле. К сожалению, не считаю пример `Observable.just(1,2,3)` достаточно полным для себя, но вот уже несколько часов мучаю себя мыслью, как превратить изменения в `EditText` в поток данных? Если не сложно, опишите, пожалуйста, пример как сделать реальный `Observable` из `TextWatcher`, чтобы можно было на него подписаться и подписчик реагировал на изменения текста в `EditText`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться готовой библиотекой [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding). Также в ней можно посмотреть [конкретную реализацию](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/widget/TextViewTextChangeEventObservable.java).

Вообще для связки `callback`-методов с `rx` используется метод `Observable.create`, например:

```
Observable.create(emitter -> {
    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        } 

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (!emitter.isDisposed()) { //если еще не отписались
                emitter.onNext(editable.toString()); //отправляем текущее состояние
            }
        }
    };
    emitter.setCancellable(() -> editText.removeTextChangedListener(watcher)); //удаляем листенер при отписке от observable
    editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);
});
```

Нужно не забыть подписаться, и самое главное, *отписаться* от такого источника данных, т.к. он держит ссылку на `editText` и может привести к утечке памяти.